# What is the fastest way to get included headers list (recursively) for .cpp file?

Tags: c++, gcc, header, preprocessor

I'm having .cpp file and i need to get full included headers list recursively.

I've tried:

```
g++ [-c] -H -E -std=gnu++11 -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -I ... file.cpp
```

but it takes about 6 seconds (tested on ARM device), which is too long. I've tried to remove `-c` but it seems it does not affect significantly. I should note i have about 40 directories in `-I` (one by one) which can increase processing time, but i have lot's of libs used so i can't reduce it.

Is there any way to do it significantly faster with GCC?

Comment: Have you checked whether you're CPU-bound or IO-bound? I wouldn't be surprised if it was the latter.

Comment: Not yet. Before doing it i'd like to make sure i did not do any obvious inefficient things

Comment: Well, posting here before checking what was slowing things down was definitely inefficient. I don't see anything else.

Comment: i expected anything like "you're running preprocessing with compilation but you can preprocess only with following flags" ...